# How can I check is each keys in this dict exist and that they all have a non empty value?

Tags: python, dictionary, operating-system, pathlib, tomlkit

I have a toml file that looks like

```
[default]
conf_path = "d"
prefix = "p"
suffix = "s"
```

I am turning this into a dict that looks like,

```
{default: {'conf_path': 'd', 'prefix': 'p', 'suffix': 's'}}
```

They key is `default` and the value is a dictionary. I want to check if `default` exists and for the dict in the value -- I want to check that the conf_path, prefix, suffix keys exist and that they all have a value that isn't `''` or `None`.

This is what I have so far. I am having trouble checking the keys and values in default's value dict.

```
def get_config_path() -> str:
    """
    """
    default_path = os.path.expanduser(const.CONFIG_PATH)
    final_path = os.environ.get('CONFIG_PATH', default_path)
    return final_path


def check_toml():
    conf = Path(get_config_path())
    default_table = ['default', 'conf_path', 'prefix', 'suffix']
    if conf.exists():
        toml_dict = tomlkit.loads(Path(get_config_path()).read_text())
        d = toml_dict['default']
        for key, value in d.items():
            d = key
    else: d = 'File does not exist.'
    return d
```

How can I check that the three specific keys exist and they each have a value?

I don't know how to check that all three keys exist, they all have a value that isn't `''` or `None`, and then say true if all of that is met.

I can do one no prob though

`if toml_dict['default'].get('conf_path') not in (None, ''):`

I was thinking use a list some how.

Comment: Python dictionaries have a built-in *get()* function. You will find that very useful

Comment: Right, but I don't know how to do it for 3 keys and check the values and then say true if all of that is met. `if toml_dict['default'].get('conf_path') not in (None, ''):`

Answer (score 1):

```
if 'default' in conf and all(key in conf['default'] and conf['default'][key] for key in ('conf_path', 'prefix', 'suffix')):
```

This makes sure that the `default` element exists, and that each of the keys you're interested in has a Truthy value (I.E. not None or '').

Comment: This is great, and it works. `toml_dict` is the dict not `conf` though. `if 'default' in toml_dict and all(key in toml_dict['default']...` But the down side to this is, I can't specify what is missing specifically in the event the table or any of the three keys is missing. But it def works. Thanks.

Comment: @DuckButts I gave the shortest code that would deliver the results you asked for.  There are of course more elaborate versions of this that would deliver additional information if that's what's required.